Как настроить celery beat для запуска парсера в проекте django?
Имеется небольшой проект на django по сбору вакансий, вот ссылка на репазиторий https://github.com/Aliaksandrsw/servicejob Для запуска парсера с определенной переодтчностью я хочу использовать celery beat, но проблема в том что при запуске celery в терминале , комады для запуска '''celery -A servicejob worker --loglevel=info''' и '''celery -A servicejob beat --loglevel=info''' не чего не проиходит, хотя воркер таски видит, так же пробовал запускать парсер через view и так же не чего не происходит, а вот если запустить вручную через shell или python console данную функцию
@shared_task
def parse_habr_vacancies():
    logger.info("Task parse_habr_vacancies started")
    url_lst = habr_get_all_url()
    vacancies = asyncio.run(habr_get_content(url_lst))
    for vacancy in vacancies:
        url = vacancy['url']
        if not Vacancy.objects.filter(url=url).exists():
            Vacancy.objects.create(
                url=url,
                title=vacancy['title'],
                company=vacancy['company'],
                skills=vacancy['skills'],
                created=vacancy['created'],
            )
    logger.info("Task parse_habr_vacancies finished")

то все работает
Помагите пожалуйста разобраться почему не запускается!!!!
